# Is there any possibility to automate Power Queries in Excel for my task?

Tags: excel, vba, automation, powerquery

I want to extract price data of investment fonds from an website to several excel sheets. Therefore I have gathered the URLs from that website in an Excel sheet as follows: [Website format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1V0Z2.jpg)
Then I created a variable that contains each of the URLs step by step In a for-loop. 
Now I recorded my macro doing the Power Query manually. After executing the macro, the desired price data is written in another excel sheet... The problem is that this only works when I type the URL manually in the Code because the macro doesn't recognize the variable which contains the URL in the following code but the variable is essential for my automation. Code:

```
Sub Abfrage()


Dim intFonds As Integer
Let intFonds = 16

Dim strFondsname As String
strFondsname = Range("E" & intFonds).Value

For intFonds = 16 To 32
strFondsname = Range("E" & intFonds).Value

'Selection.Copy
'    ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="", Formula:= _
'        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Quelle = Web.Page_
        '(Web.Contents(strFondsname = Range("E" & intFonds).Value))," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Data1 = Quelle{1}[Data]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Geänderter Typ"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Data1,{{""Datum"", Int64.Type}, {""Eröffnung"", type number}, {""Schluss"", type number}, {""Tageshoch"", type number}, {""Ta" &  "gestief"", type number}, {""Umsatz (St.)"", Int64.Type}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Geänderter Typ"""
'    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
'    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
'        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=Document;Extended Properties=""""" _
'        , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
'        .CommandType = xlCmdSql
'        .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [Document]")
'        .RowNumbers = False
'        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
'        .PreserveFormatting = True
'        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
'        .BackgroundQuery = True
'        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
'        .SavePassword = False
'        .SaveData = True
'        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
'        .RefreshPeriod = 0
'        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
'        .ListObject.DisplayName = "Document2"
'        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
'    End With
'    Sheets("Namen").Select
'    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
'    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:01:00"))
    Next intFonds



End Sub
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question with the code as text, not as a screenshot, thanks.

Comment: Why do you write the Power Query M code with a macro? Why not just create the Power Query and reference the worksheet cells in the M code? Or use parameters that read form the worksheet? Look for fnGetParameter on Ken Puls' blog http://ExcelGuru.ca